# ¿Que metodo del Adapter determina el numero de elementos que tendra un listView?

Tags: android, adapter

Pues bueno la pregunta es bien clara, necesito saber que método del adapter es el que determina cuantos elementos tendrá una listview.

cuando hablo de adapter, me refieroa baseadapter, a esto:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return null ;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Hombre pues getCount()... tiene pinta de devolver el número de elementos...

Comment: getCount(), debes hacer que retorne el tamaño del array que uses para rellenar o tu número de items

Comment: graciaaas!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de `BaseAdapter` el método es [getCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#getCount())

```
   class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public int getCount() {
            //Define el numero de elementos
            return listaElement.size();
        }

    }
```

> [getCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#getCount()) determina cuántos elementos hay en el conjunto de
>   datos representado por este adaptador.

Lo puedes ver en la clase [SimpleAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter) que es una subclase.